# How to connect to Cloud SQL from pgAdmin4?

Tags: python, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have an instance of PostgreSQL 11 in GCP as Cloud SQL.
I want to connect pgAdmin to the server but I don't know to what port. Where can I see that?

I don't want to specify my ip adress for the server and I whitelisted all the connections to the server by putting 0.0.0.0/0 as an ip in the gcp console.

Comment: Do not whitelist `0.0.0.0/0`. Use the Cloud SQL Proxy instead.

Comment: The default port is 5432 for PostgreSQL

Comment: Hoow do you connect using psql from remote machine? Use the same configuration in pgAdmin4

Answer (score 2):

Multiple methods can be used to connect Cloud SQL to external applications such as pgAdmin. [Here is the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-external-app) covering all the methods and the steps to follow. Since you do not wish to specify your ip address, then using the proxy might be a good alternative. Documentation guidelines for that method [can be found here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-external-app#proxy), but here is a quick summary:

1. Enable the API
2. Install the proxy client on your local machine
3. Determine how you will authenticate the proxy
4. If required by your authentication method, create a service account
5. Determine how you will specify your instances for the proxy
6. Start the proxy
7. Update your application to connect to Cloud SQL using the proxy